# Moving my camera to the position of player but obstacles are not showing at all

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So earlier what i was doing in my game was that my player would just stay in center of the phone horizontally and vertically and all the obstacles would come down and we are supposed to dodge them. These obstacles are also moving left and right so i started noticing that the behavior was too unrealistic like i wanted it to feel that the ball is moving upward and the obstacles are coming down but apparently it does not feel like that.

So i changed the code and i started moving the ball upwards and i stopped bringing down the obstacles.

Now what i am struggling with is that the ball is moving upward and the camera's position is same as of the ball but the obstacles do not appear and i am guessing it is happening may be because i am not spawning the obstacles correct way.

I am spawning the obstacles at the height of the phone every second.

Here is the code:

```
public void spawnSpikeWall(){
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    rect.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    rect.setSize(627,219);
    spikeWallList.add(rect);
    WallMove wm = new WallMove();
    moveList.add(wm);
}
```

The above function is responsible for creating my obstacles at the phone height. But when the ball moves upward , aren't they supposed to appear?

Comment: The x and y you're setting for every wall is some fixed position that has nothing to do with the camera position. Your original method of moving the obstacles makes more sense and is what is typically used for endless games. Otherwise, if the player travels far enough, float precision will eventually  begin to drop and that will cause problems.

Comment: But when i am moving the obstacles down, i get a unrealistic behavior , like you can always tell the obstacles are coming down and believe me it doesn't look cool.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You know what tell me a official way for how to make a game where the obstacles are supposed to come from the uppermost-side and the player should look like the player is moving up and the objects are not moving down rather they are static and also when these obstacles move right and left , they look too creepy , i dont want that behavior either.

Comment: There's no official way to do anything. Jjust making a suggestion based on things I've read before. Moving the camera and player vs. moving the obstacles is effectively the same except for the float precision issue. There's a LibGDX sample project called Superjumper that you can look at for a source code example. Its not endless or continuous, but has similar concepts. If you want less robotic movement left and right, look into interpolated movement where there's a bit of acceleration at the beginning and end of a movement to make it look natural.

Comment: So basically am i using the right logic?

Comment: It sounds spoke it from your description. If you haven't added a moving background yet, that will probably help the most. If you have it move a slower speed than the obstacles for a parallax effect, it might help even more.